# service starts automatically

Tags: android, service

I have a service for playing background music. My activity has a 2.5 secs countdown timer and when activity starts also timer starts, I've placed service starting in the OnFinish method of timer, means that music should be played 2.5 secs after activity beginning, but my problem is that music starts playing simultaneously when activity starts.
Thanks for any answer.
here's my timer:

```
if (first.getString("f", "0").equals("0")) {

    t1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    t2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    m.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    p2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    p.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    h.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    t3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(2500, 1000) {
        final ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            t1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            m.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            h.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            im.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            m.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);
            m.setTag(R.drawable.music);
            **startService(new Intent(main.this, music.class));**
            medit.putString("m", "0");
            medit.commit();
        }
    };
        Count.start();
        editor.putString("f", "1");
        editor.commit();
}
    else {
        final ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        im.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        t3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

here's my service:

```
public class music extends Service {
public music() {
}

MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(music.this, R.raw.theme);
    mp.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.stop();
}
```

}

Comment: Let me guess.. your service has started way before your timer times up.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's an abstract question - please add your code.

Comment: Probably the service start in the time you want but until the inflation end you think that is the same time. Add logs to activity and service onCreate() that print the current time.